# Claiming of tokens accidentally just stopped to work

Tags: blockchain, solidity

We we running small custom presale contract and when it filled users started to claim it.
After it around 75% was claimed users started to experience transaction reverts and no longer be able to claim their allocation.

Our claim function looks like that:

```
function claimTokens() public {
    require(finalized, "Presale is not finalized yet!");
 
    uint256 amount_ = tokenAllocation(msg.sender);
    IERC20(tokenAddress).approve(address(this), amount_);
    IERC20(tokenAddress).transferFrom(address(this), msg.sender, amount_);
}
```

There are plenty of tokens on the presale contract (address(this))

Maybe someone sees some obvious mistake here?
First I thought maybe allowance is not working properly, but that approve call should give allowance for presale address to use its tokens to send to claiming users. Also it was working for like 75% tokens claimed successfully.

Please advise

Comment: Possibly a logic error in the `tokenAllocation()` function. Can you verify what value does it return for a `msg.sender` that has the transaction reverted? How does it compare to the token balance of this contract? Can you share the `tokenAllocation()` and its dependencies as well?

Comment: TokenAllocation for users returns this: https://i.ibb.co/MyTDvF3/image.png, so I am 100% sure this part works. This is contract amount of tokens: https://i.ibb.co/dMYBDnd/image.png so it also has plenty of tokens to be send to user claiming

Maybe it is something wrong with approve and allocation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everything was OK with presale contract. The issue was with transfer of token function itself, token transfer failed because of auto liquify function restrictions